# Enabling Certificate Authority Auto-enrollment on Domain via GPO, any "dangers" I should be aware of?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, certificate-authority

I deployed a Standalone Offline Root CA and created a Sub Enterprise CA that handles enrollment and policy. There all setup correctly. I am getting ready to enable Auto-enrollment to the whole domain via default domain policy and Computer Configuration. I am satisfied with the current certificate templates that are setup.

Is there any danger to enabling this feature on a production network I might have overlooked? that could cause connectivity problems? For users or Domains etc.

I cant think of anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that:

- Renew expired certificates
- update pending certificates
- Update certificates that use certificate templates
- remove revoked certificates

are enabled in the group policy

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem in setting you autoenrollment for your computers. I would highly suggest that you start with a smaller subset - say a single OU - and apply the policy there to test the policy itself before applying it domain wide.